# Solve $\int cos{\sqrt x} \ dx$ using a combination of substitution and integration by parts

Tags: integration

My textbook says I should solve the following integral by first making a substitution, and then using integration by parts:

$$\int cos\sqrt x \ dx$$

The problem is, after staring at it for a while I'm still not sure what substitution I should make, and hence I'm stuck at the first step. I thought about doing something with the $\sqrt x$, but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere as far as I can tell. Same with the $cos$. Any hints?

Comment: Don't just think about it, actually try doing it. The substitution $t = \sqrt{x}$ is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a subs $u = \sqrt x, x = u^2, dx = 2u du$  now the integral  $\int \cos \sqrt x \, dx$ is transformed into $$2\int u \cos u \, du = 2 \int u d (\sin u) =2\left( u\sin u - \int \sin u \, du\right)  = 2\left( u\sin u +\cos u +C\right)$$

Comment: That's quite a hint. :)

Comment: @Asker, that was an error. fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try $x = u^2$, and $dx = 2u ~ du$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t^2$, then $dx=2tdt$, so
$$\int\cos\sqrt{x}dx=\int 2t\cos tdt$$

Then use integration by parts.